# How to have mandatory argument combinations with argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I am working on a CLI tool in Python that has a bunch of features. I would like to have these independent features invoked through command line

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    group_check = parser.add_argument_group('Execute State Check')
    group_check.add_argument('-c', '--check-state',  action='store_true')

    group_etl = parser.add_argument_group('Execute ETL', '3 required arguments.')
    group_etl.add_argument('-e', '--execute-etl',   action='store_true',    required=True)
    group_etl.add_argument('-o', '--region',        action='store',         required=True)
    group_etl.add_argument('-t', '--table',         action='store',         required=True)
    group_etl.add_argument('-m', '--max-date',      action='store',         required=True)

    args = parser.parse_args()
```

Unfortunately required=True is global so I cannot force that if -e is used I need to have 3 more switches present and I can use -c without those. Is there a way to have switches mandatory within a argument group?

```
./etl.py -c

usage: etl.py [-h] -e -o REGION -t TABLE -m MAX_DATE [-c]
etl.py: error: the following arguments are required: -e/--execute-etl, -o/--region, -t/--table, -m/--max-date
Tue, 10 Sep 2019 19:39:13 INFO     Quitting...
```

Comment: `required=True` does not make sense with a `store_true` argument.

Comment: `argument_group` is just a help display tool.  It does nothing to change parsing.  `mutually_exclusive_group` is the only tool for controlling interactions between arguments.  That and `subparsers`.  If neither fits your needs, you need to check for interactions after parsing.  With the default default `None`, it's easy to test whether an argument has been used or not (`args.foobar is None`).

Comment: @hpaulj thanks. It does not answer my question how to have mandatory switches with mutually exclusive groups. This is what I want -> "(-a)|(-b B -c C -d D)"

Comment: The logic in mutually_exclusive_groups is a simple, float `xor`.  I've explored writing a logically-complete grouping system, but it's messy, especially formatting a meaningful help.  Have you thought about how you'll instruct your users?

Comment: That is interesting. I thought it is rather simple. I guess I will just move the logic into the code and check if all the options are set when I need it.

Comment: Also see [Python issue 55797](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/55797)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use subcommands instead of argument groups.

```
etl.py check-state  # Do state checking
etl.py execute-et -o foo -t bar -m 2020-01-31  # Execute
```

The code would look something like

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
sp = parser.add_subparsers()
check = sp.add_parser('check-state')
execute = sp.add_parser('execute-etl')

check.set_defaults(cmd='check-state')
execute.set_defaults(cmd='execute-et')

execute.add_argument('-o')
execute.add_argument('-t')
execute.add_argument('-m')
```

If `-o`, `-t` and `-m` are required, consider making them positional arguments instead.

The default value for `cmd` is set by the subcommand used on the command line (technique adapted from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands)), effectively recording the subcommand chosen in the resulting `Namespace` instance.