# Best way to have argparse handle different options/combination of arguments

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

What is the best way to have multiple options of command line arguments based on selected options.  For example lets say we have `sample.py`

I would like to have say 3 options:

```
python sample.py Employee John Doe
python sample.py Address Washington Drive NY
python sample.py Number 1234567890
```

Was trying to add `parser.add_argument('option', choices=['Employee', 'Address', 'Number'])`, so this will limit me to have the 3 options, but I guess it would be nice to have it check the required parameters as well, and maybe a detailed help `-h`.  Say if `Employee` is chosen and only one parameter provided, it will say something like `lastname` is required.  If `Number` is selected and provides a string, it will say something like `invalid number`. Is it better to do positional arguments, or named argument, like `-num 1234567890` or -`firstname John -lastname Doe`.  Seems positional is more simple, but can be confusing if it requires 7 parameters.  How would you write the `sample.py` to use argparse and handle the simple example above

Comment: You want three [subcommands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands).

Comment: You would do best to follow conventions on command line parameters, so users don't have to guess or get frustrated using your script. And if you do, you'll find that `argparse` supports that quite handily.

Comment: i would preferr to have `--Employee` `--Address` `--Number` and run all of them in one execution, `python sample.py  --Employee "John Doe" --Address "Washington Drive NY"  --Number 1234567890`. This way I assing address to person. Because I don't like to write long strings so I would create also shorter `-e` for `Employee`, `-a` for `Address` and `-n` for `Number`

Comment: Are you going to allow just one of these options per call, or some combination?  Must the name always have 2 fields?  How about the address?  Accepting quoted strings gives you the most flexibility.  Some testing is easier done after parsing.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57875917, https://stackoverflow.com/q/19414060